# Hibernate: Cannot remove a referenced entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following JPA entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Set<A> a_objects = new HashSet<>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID", nullable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", nullable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private B b;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

}
```

I use Hibernate to find a Book entity by its Id, then remove all of its A objects. This is the code that does the work:

```
@Transactional
public void clear(Long id) {
    book = bookDao.find(id);

    a_objects = book.getAObjects();

    for(A a : a_objects) {
        aDao.remove(a);
    }
    book.getAObjects.clear();

}
```

When I just try to remove an A object I get an exception of "detached entity" so I tried a several approaches of `aDao.remove()` implementation:

```
// 1
if(!em.contains(a)){
    a = em.getReference(a.getClass(), a.getId());
}
em.remove(a);

// 2
if(!em.contains(a)){
    a = this.find(a.getId());
}
em.remove(a);

// 3
if(!em.contains(a)){
    a = em.merge(authToRemove);
}
em.remove(a);
```

All of the solutions above pass without any exception but don't actually remove anything from DB.

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**
When I remove field b from class A, and keep only the ID and BOOK_ID fields (the change is only at the Hibernate class level, not the DB tables), it removed as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Detached entity would indicate that there is no active database transaction or that the fetching and removing of the entities are happening in two different transactions. This snippet of code is not enough to be able to see what is going wrong there.

Comment: Updated the code. The find() and remove() all happens on the same function

Comment: You certainly updated the code, but not anything that matters or has to do with transaction management...

Comment: *I use Hibernate to find a Book entity by its Id, then remove all of its A objects. When I just try to remove an A object...*
This sentence doesn't make sense to me, could you elaborate or post your code on how you do this?